# Display SQL Data Type Time as Standard Time

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

My Database stores time in the SQL DataType Time.  I'm using mvc 3 in vb.net and trying to get the time to display in standard format (AM/PM).  But,  I keep getting an error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.IConvertible'."

This is the code I'm using

```
<h4>Tuesday</h4>
<ul>
@For Each c As ClassSchedule In ViewBag.Tuesday

   @<li>@c.timeStart - @c.timeEnd - @c.name</li>

Next
</ul>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is 'ClassSchedule'?

Comment: See http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/193507/How-to-operate-arithmetic-operation-on-dates

Comment: class schedule is an object: id, timestart, timeend, name

Comment: what are the types of those fields?

Comment: What is Type of timeStart and timeEnd.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

```
@<li>
  @(new DateTime(c.timeStart.Ticks).ToString("hh:mm:ss tt")) - 
  @(new DateTime(c.timeEnd.Ticks).ToString("hh:mm:ss tt")) - @c.name
</li>
```

<strike>Eror Occured becuse you subtract Dates</strike>

```
 @<li>
   <span>@c.timeStart </span>- 
   <span>@c.timeEnd </span>- 
   <span>@c.name</span>
  </li>
```

Comment: It works fine when it is not trying to convert the format to datetime.  This is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly call ToString() on your TimeSpan.

Comment: I've tried this:   @<li>@c.timeStart.ToString("t") - @c.timeEnd - @c.name</li>  -- but it doesn't work

Comment: why do you think you have to call ToString with "t" as the parameter?

Comment: converting to standard time?  the issue isnt displaying the time -- its displaying it in the standard format

Comment: check this out: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vblanguage/thread/1aceb10e-7408-42a9-ab63-44ae21dd5358

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out --- you have to convert the time into a string first

@

@Convert.ToDateTime(c.timeStart.ToString).ToShortTimeString - @Convert.ToDateTime(c.timeEnd.ToString).ToShortTimeString - @c.name